# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required complex type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, wsdl

Converting an existing wsdl project over to spring boot rest, one of the endpoints requires a parameter that is a complex type which is  made up of yet another complex type. When I  make a request to the endpoint I get error of

**"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type HistComplexType"**

The web request is along the lines of https://someserver:port/myendpoint/command?command=<xml ...>

Comment: WSDL isn't REST so it won't work (it was SOAP for a reason). If you want to parse the content you need to send it as the body not as a parameter.